# When is the integral of $x^{-1} = \ln \lvert x \rvert$?

Tags: integration, substitution

In my textbook there is a question that says:

> Use either a suitable substitution or the reverse chain rule to find the following integrals.

$$ \int \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2}}\right) dx$$

Using substitution I came down to:

$${1\over 2} \int u^{-{1\over2}}du$$
where $u=x^2+2$

Couldn't this be rewritten as $${1\over 2} \int (\sqrt{u})^{-1}$$ And isn't that equivalent to $${1\over 2}\log|\sqrt{u}| + c$$ where $\sqrt{u}$ acts as $x$?

The thing is the answer is $\sqrt{x^2 +2} + c$. And so I don't know if I fully understand the theory behind integrating $1/x$ and $\log|x|$.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ .

Comment: What is going on? Is LaTeX going out of fashion?

Comment: You're right that $∫ 1/x dx = \ln|x| + C$. How you then got to $∫ 1/\sqrt{x} dx = \ln|\sqrt{x}| + C$ is beyond me.

Comment: You've omitted a step in the $u$-substitution, coincident with dropping the $dx,du$ notation from integrals.

Comment: it only applies where the power on the x is $-1$ you cannot split the power up like this and treat it as the same function

Comment: The reason it only works for $\int\frac{1}{x}dx$ is because this fits the general formula $\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=ln(f(x))+C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int \frac {1}{u} du = \ln |u|+C.$  However, $\int \frac {1}{f(u)}\ du \ne \ln |f(u)|$

That is, you can only integate into a logarthm if, by u-substitutions you can get the denominator with that lone $u.$

For this problem we have a power rule you can employ:

$\int u^a du = \frac {u^{a+1}}{a+1} + C$ (which works for all constants $a\ne -1$ )

Comment: Ah, right. But if I was to integrate $\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{2u+4}du$ wouldn't I get $\frac{1}{2}ln|2u+4|+c$? Or is it because I can rewrite $\frac{1}{2u+4}$ as $\frac{1}{u}$ plus something else?

Comment: $\int \frac {1}{ax+b} \ dx = \frac {1}{a} \ln |ax+b| +C$ but that is because you are able to do the substitution $u = ax+b$ to isolate $u$ in the denominator.  I would say stick with this extra step until you are more comfortable knowing when you can combine the two steps at once.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

- for $x>0$ $$f(x)=\ln |x|=\ln x\implies f’(x)=\frac1x$$
- for $x<0$ $$g(x)=\ln |x|=\ln (-x)\implies g’(x)=-\frac1{-x}=\frac1x$$